# How convert input from EditText to 8 digit Number

Tags: android

I am having trouble displaying the text in a text view. I want to convert the input numbers from `EditText` to 8 digits by filling Zeros.
Say if I type in `EditText` as 123 The output in `Textview` Should be 00000123 or 
say I type in `EditText` as 1234 the Output should be 00001234.
How I should do it in `Android Studio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help.

```
String input = "123";
String finalString = ("00000000" + input).substring(input.length())
```

If you started with a number instead:

```
Int inputNumber = 123;
String formattedNumber = String.format("%08d", inputNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks This one Did The Job..

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add zeros in front:

```
String yourString = String.format("%08d", yournumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

For zero-padding with a length of 8

```
String.format("%08d", yournumber);
ex:
String value= String.format("%08d", 123);
```

output is **00000123**